# Creating a 3-dimensional array of excel files in R

Tags: r, arrays, excel

I have the following MWE, although the datasets are unavailable:

```
N <- 84 #Number of datasets to pull data from
dates <-  c("2010.01", "2010.02", "2010.03", "2010.04", "2010.05", "2010.06", "2010.07", "2010.08",
 "2010.09", "2010.10", "2010.11", "2010.12", "2011.01", "2011.02", "2011.03", "2011.04", "2011.05",
 "2011.06", "2011.07", "2011.08", "2011.09", "2011.10", "2011.11", "2011.12", "2012.01", "2012.02",
 "2012.03", "2012.04", "2012.05", "2012.06", "2012.07", "2012.08", "2012.09", "2012.10", "2012.11",
 "2012.12", "2013.01", "2013.02", "2013.03", "2013.04", "2013.05", "2013.06", "2013.07", "2013.08",
 "2013.09", "2013.10", "2013.11", "2013.12", "2014.01", "2014.02", "2014.03", "2014.04", "2014.05",
 "2014.06", "2014.07", "2014.08", "2014.09", "2014.10", "2014.11", "2014.12", "2015.01", "2015.02", 
 "2015.03", "2015.04", "2015.05", "2015.06", "2015.07", "2015.08", "2015.09", "2015.10", "2015.11", 
 "2015.12", "2016.01", "2016.02", "2016.03", "2016.04", "2016.05", "2016.06", "2016.07", "2016.08",
 "2016.09", "2016.10", "2016.11", "2016.12") #list of all dates to loop through

A <- list() #empty list to store excel files
for (k in seq_along(dates)) {
  A[k] <- read_excel(paste0("~/R/data.", dates[k], ".xlsx"), range = "B3:EO94")
}
Total <- array(unlist(A), dim=c(91,144,84))

First <- read_excel(paste0("~R/data.", dates[1], ".xlsx"), range="B3:EO94")
```

This gives me `Total` the 3-dimensional array and then `First` which should be the first "slice" of the array. So if I take some arbitrary coordinate, say 15,34, then I should be able to pull the exact some value from both `Total` and `First` so I try the following:

```
> Total[15,34,1]
[1] 0.000392432

> A1[15,34]
# A tibble: 1 x 1
   `-97.5`
     <dbl>
1 0.000384
```

The 0.000384 is the proper number found in the excel file from AI18 and the number given from `Total` is incorrect. What gives? To further double-check I compared `Total[15,34,2]` with the second "slice" and alas, the same incorrect result from `Total`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the double square brackets, `A[[k]]` to assign the data from the Excel files.

```
A <- list() #empty list to store excel files

for (k in seq_along(dates)) {
  A[[k]] <- read_excel(paste0("~/R/data.", dates[k], ".xlsx"), range = "B3:EO94")
}
```